# Вылетает приложение при просмотре видео Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

Помогите , проблемы с при открытие видео

Код Java класса тут https://disk.asterios.ws/s/wej8BmCum2sTlxc

Вот код ошибки

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: ru.mrvilitin.network, PID: 18230
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.mrvilitin.network/ru.mrvilitin.network.VideoViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
      at ru.mrvilitin.network.VideoViewActivity.onCreate(VideoViewActivity.java:74)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
```

Comment: Не надо ссылок на код, особенно, если это не gitHub или аналоги. По подозрительным ссылкам мало кто ходит, к тому же она протухнет и вопрос потеряет смысл для будущих посетителей, а помощь именно им - основная цель сайта. Выложите код текстом прямо в вопрос - так будет правильно. По сути вопроса - у вас нет проблемы с видео, у вас проблема с `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`. Вы или ID не тот указали или не там или в стилях что-то не то. Не глядя в код сложно сказать точно.

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий! Сейчас посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Как уже говорил [@ЮрийСПБ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) у вас приложение не находит toolbar, проблема в этой строке:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

а вот сама проблема:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

в этой ошибке говорится что программа пытается вызвать метод связанный с тулбаром,а именно отобразить иконку крестика на тулбаре, при том что самого тулбара нет. И поэтому ваше приложение падает постоянно. Я бы вам посоветовал три варианта:

1. Убрать эту кнопку и не использовать ее на этой активности
2. Как уже сказано в комментариях - пересмотреть стили. В стилях которые применяются к данной активности может значится что эта активность не имеет тулбара. Значит вам нужно либо создать стиль для этой активности либо переделать уже имеющийся.
3. Добавить в вашу разметку тулбар. Я вижу вы что-то такое пытались сделать в этих строках:

   ```
   // Toolbar t = (Toolbar)
   //  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   // setSupportActionBar(t);
   ```

но с учетом того что они заккоментированы, я так понимаю вы забросили эту идею. Так вот добавить тулбар можно в разметку и уже дальше работать с ним из класса активности.

P.S. я бы вам советовал отредактировать вопрос так как его закроют. Добавить кусок вашего класса со строкой где возникает ошибка. Пользователь не всегда хочет идти в какие-то дебри чтобы посмотреть ваш класс.

Comment: Спасибо , попробую и отпишусь !

Comment: Решением было заменить getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
на
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: а кнопка крестика отображалась?

Comment: Да, отображается, все работает

Comment: К слову вот репозиторий с этим проектом https://github.com/saintvili/AsteriosSocialNetwork